# UIViewPropertyAnimator not stopping properly with pan gesture between views

Tags: swift, uikit, uiviewanimation

I have a view controller that setups 3 children view controllers, puts the three views side by side, and centers the middle view.. like snapchat. The sliding between view controllers is controlled by using a pangesture that adjusts the left anchor constraint of the far left child view controller.

Right now... when I pan and then let go it will go to the proper constraint.

THE ISSUE: when I pan, let go, pan again the constraints snap back and the animation isn't looking proper. Any insight would be appreciated....

this link shows what I mean by the constraint and animations snapping and being funky!! (the first pan is proper, but when i try to interrupt the second pan you see my issue)

https://giphy.com/gifs/mEDld5sbR81gJBHcl1

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let viewControllerOne = UIViewController()
    private let viewControllerTwo = UIViewController()
    private let viewControllerThree = UIViewController()

    private var viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        //removed code for stackoverflow readability, here i setup view controllers and pangestures

        guard let viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint = viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint else { return }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            viewControllerOne.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            viewControllerTwo.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            viewControllerThree.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),

            viewControllerOne.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            viewControllerTwo.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            viewControllerThree.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            viewControllerOne.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            viewControllerTwo.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            viewControllerThree.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),

            viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint,
            viewControllerTwo.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewControllerOne.view.rightAnchor),
            viewControllerThree.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewControllerTwo.view.rightAnchor),

        ])


    }

    private var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?
    private var previous: CGPoint?
    private var current: CGPoint?

    @objc private func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint = viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint else { return }
        if gesture.state == .began {
            previous = gesture.location(in: view)
            animator?.stopAnimation(true)
        } else if gesture.state == .changed {
            let current = gesture.location(in: view)
            guard let previous = previous else { return }
            let xPositionDifference = current.x - previous.x
            if viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint.constant + xPositionDifference < 0 && viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint.constant + xPositionDifference > -(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2) {
                self.viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint?.constant += xPositionDifference
                self.previous = current
            }
        } else if gesture.state == .ended {
            viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint.constant = calculateLeftAnchorConstant(viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint: viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint)
            animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2.0, curve: .easeOut) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            animator?.startAnimation()
        }
    }

    func calculateLeftAnchorConstant(viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint) -> CGFloat {
        if viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint.constant <= 0
            && viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint.constant > -(UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.0) {
            return 0.0
        } else if viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint.constant > -(UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.0 * 3)
            && viewControllerOneLeftAnchorConstraint.constant < -(UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2.0) {
            return -(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        } else {
            return -(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Animation and constraints are opposites, and a property view animator is for animating view properties, not constraints. This whole approach is probably inadvisable. Try removing the constraints during the animation and letting the property animator animate frames etc.

Comment: any suggestions on a better approach? really just want to nail down this UI flow so it stops and starts properly... I don't really know what you mean by removing constraints. like deactivate?

Comment: Well, it's hard for me to answer because this seems to me to be an x-y question. I can't quite tell what the _real_ goal is. It seems to be a "carousel" or paging scroll view where the user can slide the interface from one view to another and it "snaps" into place in the center of the screen. You seem to have assumed that the way to do this is to do this is with constraints and a property animator. It isn't. But you see, you didn't ask _how_ to do it: you _assumed_ a way of doing it and now it isn't working (because it isn't the right way). Try a UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you to abandon the entirety of your code. Your words and your animated gif are describing a UIPageViewController, so why not *use* a UIPageViewController?